# Why do the $2$-Selmer ranks of $y^2 = x^3 + p^3 $ and $y^2 = x^3 - p^3 $ agree?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

I was playing around with *sage*, when I found that the Mordell-Weil ranks (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3+p^3$ and $y^2=x^3-p^3 $ almost always agree, for $p$ prime. The first few exceptions occur at $p=37$, $p=61$, $p=157$, $p=193$, $\ldots$. This pattern struck me as odd, since the two curves are non-isogenous over the ground field, so why would their ranks be correlated?

After some reflection and further experimentation, I found out that if one looks instead at the *$2$-Selmer ranks*, there is even a stronger pattern: they seem to agree for *all* primes $p>2$.

I verified this using the following code, written in *sage*:

> ```
> for p in primes(100):
>     E1 = EllipticCurve(QQ,[0,p^3])
>     E2 = EllipticCurve(QQ,[0,-p^3])
>     print("p = "+QQ(p).str()+":"),
>     rank1 = E1.selmer_rank()
>     rank2 = E2.selmer_rank()
>     print([rank1,rank2])
> ```

which gives

> ```
> p = 2: [2, 1] p = 3: [1, 1] p = 5: [1, 1] p = 7: [2, 2] p = 11: [2, 2]
> p = 13: [1, 1] p = 17: [1, 1] p = 19: [2, 2] p = 23: [2, 2] p = 29: [1, 1]
> p = 31: [2, 2] p = 37: [3, 3] p = 41: [1, 1] p = 43: [2, 2] p = 47: [2, 2]
> p = 53: [1, 1] p = 59: [2, 2] p = 61: [3, 3] p = 67: [2, 2] p = 71: [2, 2]
> p = 73: [1, 1] p = 79: [2, 2] p = 83: [2, 2] p = 89: [1, 1] p = 97: [1, 1]
> ```

I have been trying to prove this by following a case distinction according to the residue class of $p$ modulo $12$, and performing a partial $2$-descent for each case, but I keep getting distracted by the thought that
there must be a neater explanation that I'm missing. Hence my question:

> **Is there?**

---

**Edit:** It might be useful to note that similar Sage experiments suggest that also (a) the $2$-Selmer ranks of the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3 \pm p$ and $y^2=x^3 \mp p^5$ agree for all $p>2$ and (b) the $2$-Selmer ranks of the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3 \pm p^2$ and $y^2=x^3 \mp p^4$ agree tot all $p>2$.

In fact, here's a conjecture, also born out by computer experiments, which goes even further and subsumes all cases mentioned before:

> **Conjecture.** Let $a$ be an odd jnteger. Then the $2$-Selmer ranks of the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3 + a$ and $y^2=x^3-a^{-1}$ (which of course is isomorphic to $y^2=x^3 - a^5$) are equal.

We get the original statement with $a=p^3$, we get (a) with $a=\pm p$, and (b) with $a=\pm p^2$.

Comment: Both groups live in ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-3})^\times$ mod squares. Did you check whether the groups are actually equal as subgroups of this quotient?

Comment: No, but that's a good idea. What I did do was checking whether a certain more easily checkable consequence of (both groups being equal as subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})^\times/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})^{\times 2}$) held, and it did.

Comment: Since the two elliptic curves are quadratic twists of each other (by the quadratic character cut out by $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$), their 2-torsion subgroups are canonically isomorphic as Galois modules, so one can identify $H^1(\mathbb{Q},E_1[2])$ with $H^1(\mathbb{Q},E_2[2])$. The respective 2-Selmer groups are therefore subgroups of this common overgroup, given by (potentially different) local conditions. By Mazur-Rubin, Ranks of twists of elliptic curves and Hilbert’s tenth
problem, Lemma 2.10, the local conditions are equal at all places except possibly 2, 3, and $p$. contd...

Comment: ... One could try to analyse carefully what happens to the local conditions at those remaining places under twisting, which should lead to a comparison of the 2-Selmer ranks.

Comment: @AlexB. That certainly looks promising, but the conditions of Lemma 2.10 do not seem to apply for my $E$ and $v \in \{2,3\}$, since at these $v$ my curve has additive reduction, and $2$ and $3$ are non-split in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})/\mathbb{Q}$. Similarly, if $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, the Lemma doesn't apply for $v=p$. (Maybe if you look carefully at the proofs, you could do something, but I don't know.)

Comment: No, I would not necessarily expect the local conditions at 2, 3, and $p$ to be the same for the two curves. But if you get lucky, then the twisting changes these conditions in "opposite directions", so that the Selmer rank does not change in the end. As I say, this would actually require careful analysis.

Comment: Oh, sure, I misread what you wrote. I get it now, thanks!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357378/cohns-eight-diophantine-equations#comment898494_357378

Comment: It is not difficult to show that the root numbers of the curve $y^2=x^3+a$ and $y^2=x^3-a^5$ are equal (using for example an explicit formulae by Eric Liverance). This, plus the parity conjecture, will imply that your conjecture is true $\pmod{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Your curves seem to be quadratic twists of each other. There are many results in the literature about ranks of such curves. E.g. 
[*Ranks of quadratic twists of elliptic curves*](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~taf1000/papers/rankcongr.html) by Donnelly and others, using Stoll's formula for the size of a Selmer group. Chang (in [*Note on the rank of quadratic twists
of Mordell equations*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510001.pdf)) studied Mordell curves of certain type (your curves are Mordell curves).

Comment: Yes, I noticed they are quadratic twists; in particular, all the pairs become isomorphic over fields containing $\sqrt{-1}$. However, I do not see how that helps out a lot...

Answer (score 5):

The (Selmer) ranks of the isogenous twists $y^2=x^3+D$ and $y^2=x^3-27D$ satisfy various relations that often mean the ranks are equal (or differ by 1). I realize these are not the pairs you're studying, but the theory, and especially the techniques, might well be applicable. (Actually, if you work over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3)$, then $y^2=x^3-27D$ is isomorphic to $y^2=x^3-D$, so that would be your situation.) Here are a couple of references to get you started, they'll contain information about how the problem has been approached.

- MR1451686 Chen, Yen-Mei J. The Selmer groups of elliptic curves and
  the ideal class groups of quadratic fields. *Comm. Algebra* **25**
  (1997), no. 7, 2157–2167.
- MR0846960 Satgé, Philippe. Groupes de
  Selmer et corps cubiques. *J. Number Theory* **23** (1986), no. 3,
  294–317.

Comment: +1. Thank you, I appreciate this.